# How can I do line breaks in a formatted string string python3

Tags: python-3.x, string, format

simple question that I hope has a simple answer

I want to store a formatted string to pass later to function call. I would like to have line breaks baked into one long string rather than send a string for each line. So for example

```
b = f'hello \n world' 
b
```

this gives me 'hello \n world' which is not what I want.

How can I do this in a compact manner. I would prefer to avoid joins or something like that with a newline separator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are seeing the `\n` because you use the automatic print function of the REPL. Try `print(b)`.

Comment: @Selcuk thanks for the reply. I need the new line independent of how I print because I am going to pass the variable to openCV put text and I want a multi line result. Is there anyway to store what print would give me to a variable?

Comment: This is not possible and you are worried for no reason. REPL will never print newlines because it uses the `__repr__` method of the object which automatically escapes newlines for the `str` class. OpenCV will use that string just fine.

Comment: @Selcuk it is reading the string it is just my newline character \n,\r or \r\n just turn into question marks. I just get one really long line of text. I gave this trivial example just to make it quick to my point.

Comment: That's a different question, specifically related to opencv. Post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue.